# Jsp fie uploading to apache server in eclipse

Tags: java

I am able to save photo's name in database but i can't find uploaded photo in  folder.. it remains empty.. the structure is as follows : 
Upload code jsp file is drectly under Web content of eclipse . The folder to store images is also under Web content. ![ can someone tell me the path to be mentioned in getrealpath +" "] or what elsecould be the issue...  this is my code
File savedFile=new File(config.getservletcontext().getrealpath("/")+"/WebContent/foldername/"+real);

Comment: What is the current path you using ?

Comment: File savedfile=new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/../../")+"/WebContent/dp/"+real);

Comment: When you printed this to console, is that path same ?

Comment: a long path appraoching towards end is :  wtpwebapps\nameofproject\/WebContent/dp/imagename.jpg

Comment: But this long path came out with when iused getRealpAth(""") means nothing inside quotes....

Comment: Othetwise path was starting with null by using getrealpath("/../../") @S R SH